# NTP symmetric key authentication to chrony servers

Tags: linux, ntp, chrony

Pretty simple question (I think), but in reading chrony's own docs and perusing through RedHat's docs, I can't find a firm answer. Probably because it's too dumb of a question to need an answer :P

If a chrony server is currently allowing clients to use it as a source without any authentication, and then a key gets added to /etc/chrony.keys, will that then effectively require *all* clients to start authenticating from then on or will unauthenticated still function?

Since there would need to be a key-pair for each connecting client I would guess the answer is that unauthenticated connections would continue to work, but this is one of those things that I would really rather not find out I am wrong about after the fact.

Comment: if you add a key to `/etc/chrony.keys`, wouldn't that require you to restart chrony to become effective, therefore disconnecting any current connections?

Comment: Sorry, I was using "connect" in a looser sense. Yes, adding a key would require restarting the service. I'm just trying to make sure that unauthenticated NTP connections would still work even after a particular client starts connecting with authentication.